# Is there a line editor for Windows (like Edlin, but better)

Tags: windows, command-line, text-editors

The first interactive computer I used (in 1972) was made by Prime.  The only editor provided was a line editor, and despite the interface it was a powerful tool.  You could do things like:

```
t
f"hello";n3;p;*
```

which translates as "go to the top of the file, find the string 'hello', move down 3 lines, print the line to the console, repeat until the end of the file".

I realise this is the sort of thing that can be done with scripts, but my favourite editor doesn't have scripting, and I regularly encounter situations where the old Prime editor would be handy.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Vim` or `gVim` in Windows as well.

Its history dates back to `ed`, which was the original Unix text editor. `ed` was used in a time when it was still common to print out source code onto pieces of paper. Computers were slow, they could easily be outpaced by quick typists. Therefore it was necessary to be very efficient when editing. This efficiency remained through all of `ed`s successors (em, en, ex, vi, vim/gvim, neovim).

In Vim, you would enter `gg/hello<Enter>3j:echom(getline('.'))<Enter>` *(I don't quite understand why you would want to output text to a console you are already in)*'. There are a ton of other commands, even a whole grammar to achieve almost exactly what you want with only two or three keypresses. Just head over to Youtube and watch some videos on Vim or try it yourself by [installing it](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc)!

A good way to start vim is installing it and then run `vimtutor`.

Comment: The example I gave was where I had a text file of many thousands of lines  which contained many instances of an identifier ("hello" in the example), but I was only after the line that was 3 lines after each occurrence of the string.  Grep isn't good at that sort of thing (well not without resorting to regex stuff).  I'll take a look at `vim`.  Thanks.

Comment: @rossmcm: FWIW, the `ex` line-editor mode still remains part of vim and can be accessed via `:ex`.

Answer (score 1):

There are [ports](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freedos-edlin/) of edlin for modern Windows machines.  Google for more.

Comment: I remember a columnist in `byte` magazine who wrote *"I would rather pick up a skin rash than a copy of EDLIN"* ;-)